Which is the most accurate protein-protein interaction prediction tool?
Among many tools available for predicting protein-protein interaction, which one is the most accurate? By accurate, I mean most close to experimental data. I shortlisted HADDOCK, ClusPro, GRAMM-X and Rossetta. The reason I am asking this question is because using the same protein X and Y, the predicted combined structure is different for different tools. There is PDB structure for both X and Y protein. I want to mutate one of the proteins at multiple locations and check how the interaction changes.
I know that there are many more like Hex, AutoDock Vina, ZDOCK, MEGADOCK, Glide, PatchDock but they are either primarily for protein-small molecule docking or hasn't been updated in a long time.

From what I understand comparing the tools is difficult because most of them use their own scoring system. That being said there are some papers that do attempt comparing https://www.mdpi.com/2079-6382/12/3/463. Do keep in mind these fields evolve rapidly, so these comparisons could be outdated by now, and comparisons are probably sensitive to application.
